# Path for icon used in smart button

Tags: button, icons, odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I am not able to find path for icon used on smart buttons for e.g. In MRP we are having "Bill of Materials" button and icon name is "fa-flask".

I already checked in web/staic/src/img/icons and local module too.

Is it stored somewhere in binary form or is it some kind of fonts?

Answer (score 3):

Odoo smart button uses http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

It is a font icon more than a image defined inside a css class. But you can change whatever as you did in css image class.

For simple idea about font awesome go through this page http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

For more information regarding odoo smart button look http://www.slideshare.net/openobject/odoo-smart-buttons

This package is located in Odoo as a library in `addons/web/static/lib/fontawesome/fonts`

Your `fa-flask` icon and a simple example to use it, is available at http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/flask/

Answer (score 2):

"fa-flask" is [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icon and it is stored at addons/web/static/lib/fontawesome , you can use any font awesome icons wherever you need.